# Using Phoenix minimal jar

Tags: jar, apache-phoenix

I want the phoenix client jar without any dependencies to use in my application. Where can I find that? How to confirm that a particular jar is a fat jar?

Answer (score 1):

phoenix-client-*jar doesnot have any dependency.. it connects with phoenix-server-*.jar which must be copied to all hbase region servers. make sure that your client.jar and server.jar have same version.

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/Phoenix" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="" password="" driverClassName="com.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver"
           url="jdbc:phoenix:<zookeepr_quoram>:2181"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix client depends on hbase client and zookeeper client jar. So, I think if the phoenix jar file don't include any dependencies, it would not be able to connect to phoenix server.